# forEach not a function but my data already in array

Tags: foreach

I have try a foreach like this

```
obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));
console.log(obj);
obj.forEach(function (new_event) {

}
```

my obj in console.log is shown like this

```
[{"id":"4ab92d98-5a72-11e8-9945-5600014a6ae6","event_type_id":"6a4f49a1-5a71-11e8-a754-28c2dd6dbd52","title":"Pameran Motor Besar","details":"Pameran 1 Tahun Sekali","start":"2017-11-21 13:00:00","end":"2017-11-23 13:00:00","all_day":"1","status":"Scheduled","active":"0","sls_kode":"PRJ","lead_code":"AKM","activity_code":"PMB","created":"2017-11-17 09:51:00","crea_by":"0","modified":"2017-11-18 09:51:00","modi_by":"0","kunci":"1","location_name":"PRJ Kemayoran","radius":"2","longitude":"106.3301545","latitude":"-6.4406122","event_code":"A01"},{"id":"4ab948d1-5a72-11e8-9945-5600014a6ae6","event_type_id":"6a6158f6-5a71-11e8-a754-28c2dd6dbd52","title":"Pameran Sweet Honda","details":"Pameran rangka valentine","start":"2017-02-14 12:00:00","end":"2017-02-16 12:00:00","all_day":"1","status":"Scheduled","active":"0","sls_kode":"WMS","lead_code":"BBN","activity_code":"PSH","created":"2017-02-11 12:14:00","crea_by":"0","modified":"2017-02-11 12:15:00","modi_by":"0","kunci":"1","location_name":"Wahana Makmur Sejati","radius":"1","longitude":"106.8343266","latitude":"-6.155052","event_code":"A02"},{"id":"4ab94e81-5a72-11e8-9945-5600014a6ae6","event_type_id":"6a615ad7-5a71-11e8-a754-28c2dd6dbd52","title":"Pameran Ramadhan","details":"Pameran rangka bulan suci ramadhan","start":"2017-07-07 12:00:00","end":"2017-08-07 12:00:00","all_day":"1","status":"Scheduled","active":"0","sls_kode":"WMS","lead_code":"RMD","activity_code":"PRN","created":"2017-08-02 12:30:00","crea_by":"0","modified":"2017-08-02 12:40:00","modi_by":"0","kunci":"1","location_name":"Wahana Makmur Sejati","radius":"1","longitude":"106.8343266","latitude":"-6.155052","event_code":"A03"}]
```

but when I try to run is shown obj.forEach is not a function
any help is appreciate, thankyou :)

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(obj.length)`

Comment: it shown 3751 @NickA

Comment: Then it looks more like obj is a string, not an array. Why are you calling `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: thankyou sir, it solved using `JSON.parse(body)` @NickA

Comment: When your question is resolved, please post the resolution as a new answer and accept it as a solution.